# When passing data to an App in mule cloudhub via API gateway(CloudHub) getting exception -HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, cloudhub

Am having an HTTP connector and a HTTPS connector which runs in API gatewayruntime in cloudhub. I want to pass the data through this API gateway to another application but while passing at the endpoint am getting
HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes Exception

Exception stack trace: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes. at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.readHeader(HttpMessageDecoder.java:596) at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.readHeaders(HttpMessageDecoder.java:503) at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:193) + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in connector configuration to suppress the header session

```
<http:connector name="NoSessionConnector" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
<service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>
</http:connector>
```

Comment: @Satheesh could elaborate on why it worked, would be nice to hear about your analysis

Comment: @Sudarshan the header contains session and hence its more than 8192 bytes so we have to make it null hence i used org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler to make it null so we wont get anything in header

Comment: Is there something specific in this application which creates a session that results in a header greater than 8192 bytes?, why doesn't this issue occur with most other apps ?

Comment: Normally if you pass a data from one clouhub application  to another using http endpoint  it will happen.